# Maven vert.x jdbc project unable to find c3p0.properties file on classpath to configure c3p0 retry attempts

Tags: java, maven, vert.x, c3p0

I have a vert.x maven project using the vertx-jdbc-client version 3.6.0 and according to the [vertx jdbc docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_configuration) there are some basic c3p0 configs you can specify in the config object passed in when creating a JDBCClient, but for the rest you need to use a c3p0.properties file on the classpath.  I placed the c3p0.properties file in src/main/resources/c3p0.properties with:

```
initialPoolSize=1
acquireRetryAttempts=1
```

I verified that the c3p0.properties file is in `target/classes` after the build, the log output even changes on startup, where it used to say

```
10:52:57.388 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig - The configuration file for resource identifier '/c3p0.properties' could not be found. Skipping.
```

It no longer says this with the file there, so it seems it is finding it. But the values are not being respected, I still get the default initial pool size (3) and retry attempts (30).

What am I doing wrong? Any solutions for advanced c3p0 configurations in a maven vertx project?

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446266/c3p0-configurations-where-and-how

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#c3p0_properties) the properties should be prefixed with `c3p0.`.